# Golden section search method that terminate after $n$ iterations

Tags: mathematical-optimization, iterators, procedural-programming

I am attempting to code a program that executes the golden section search method, and I would like to terminate the computations after $n$ iterations, where the user decides what $n$ is. My code works and finds the solution; it just refuses to terminate until the other termination condition is met.

Upon investigation, I discovered that unlike the Fibonacci Search method, this method is independent of $n$; in essence, $n$ did not matter.

Here is my code: (I appreciate edits to make it look better)

```
GoldenSearch[lower_, upper_, iterations_] := 
  Module[{a = N[lower], b = N[upper], n = iterations}, k = 0;
    Print["Iteration Results are:"];
    While[Abs[(b - (b - a)/phi) - (a + (b - a)/phi)] > Res, 
      c = (b - (b - a)/phi);
      d = (a + (b - a)/phi);
      If[G[c] < G[d],(*Then*)b = d;(*Else*)k = k + 1;, 
      a = c;
      Print[{"Lowerbound at iteration...", k, PaddedForm[a, {7, 6}]}];
      Print[{"Upperbound at iteration...", k, PaddedForm[b, {7, 6}]}];
      k++;]]];
```

It is clear that `n` does not appear anywhere else besides the `Module` function.

Here is some information on the variables and the function `G`:

- `G[x_]`: function being evaluated.
- `phi`: Golden Ratio = 1.61803...
- `a` & `b`: Lower and upper bounds
- `Res`: Resolution, I set it at `10^-4`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you're concerned that it doesn't actually terminate after `n` iterations? If so, I don't see a `k<=n` in your `While` loop, for a start.

Comment: Yeah, I don't. Would it work if I just added ",<=n" after the absolute value stuff? I was thinking of putting in another IF statement. Sorry if this sounds silly, I am extremely bad at coding.

Comment: I believe you'd want `While[Abs[(b - (b - a)/phi) - (a + (b - a)/phi)] > Res && k < n, ...]`. (didn't test it myself)

Comment: Thank you, it worked! This is sort of similar to C now that I think about it...

Comment: The bulk of Mathematica's core is written in C, so you'll notice a lot of similarities :)

Comment: The value of `phi` is built in as [`GoldenRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GoldenRatio.html)

Answer (score 4):

Just for reference, I'll present a pretty traditional implementation of golden section search. I'll use Newton's cubic $x^3-2x-5$ as the example function, minimized over $[-1,2]$:

```
f[x_] := x^3 - 2 x - 5
a = N[-1]; b = N[2];
```

`GoldenRatio` is built-in, so let's use that for making the needed constants:

```
{ψ, ϕ} = {1 - 1/GoldenRatio, 1/GoldenRatio} // N;
```

Set up the tolerance and the maximum number of iterations:

```
tol = 1.*^-4; kmax = 10;
```

Starting conditions:

```
m1 = Rescale[ψ, {0, 1}, {a, b}];
m2 = Rescale[ϕ, {0, 1}, {a, b}];
f1 = f[m1]; f2 = f[m2]; k = 0;
```

Finally, the main search:

```
While[Abs[b - a] > tol (Abs[m1] + Abs[m2]) && k < kmax, k = k + 1;
      If[f1 < f2,
         b = m2; m2 = m1; m1 = ψ a + ϕ m2;
         f2 = f1; f1 = f[m1],
         a = m1; m1 = m2; m2 = ϕ m1 + ψ b;
         f1 = f2; f2 = f[m2]];
      Print[{k, a, m1, m2, b}]];
```

which should yield `{a, m1, m2, b} = {0.805318, 0.814635, 0.820393, 0.82971}` when it finishes, and print the values along the way. If you want to get even more fancy, you can use `Plot[]` with `Epilog` to see how these points move along. If you want to compare with the built-in minimizer, you can also do `FindArgMin[f[x], {x, 1}][[1]]`.

I'll leave the encapsulation into a routine up to you.

Comment: Very neat and easily understandable! The plots would be a neat addition.